# Find all static references to a class by code c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I search for a way to display all static occurances of classes  (similiar to the Visual Studio functionality: find all references).

It should only be by code and not manually.

I want to

1. Only list classes with a specific attribute
2. List all classes which have static references to it (find table bindings to data classes)

My first step is to list all Types which i'm interested in:

```
            var result = from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                         where t.IsDefined(typeof(TAttribute), inherit)
                         select t;

            return result.ToList();
```

I'm having problems with the second step. 
I know how to find Properties... from a class. But how is it possible to go the other way round, and find all usages of a class?

Answer (score 3):

You can not find static *references* using reflection, it's something that `AST` may know about.  For this you may want to use: [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) (Compiler as  a Service), that let's you compile, and investigate AST.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find references in method bodies using reflection but you can find fields, properties and methods parameters/return values.

You already know how to list all types, now for each type:

`Type.GetProperties` returns an array of `PropertyInfo`, you can check if `PropertyInfo.ProeprtType' is in the list of types you care about.

Same goes for fields with `Type.GetFields`

For methods you call `Type.GetMethods`, this returns an array of `MethodInfo` objects, to get the return type you check `MethodInfo.ReturnType` and for the parameters call `MethodInfo.GetParameters` and `ParameterInfo.ParameterType`

That's only leaves local variables defined inside method bodies and those cannot be accessed with reflections

Comment: My main problem with the answer is that i search mainly for local variables. (For example if a grid is initialized with a specific type)

Comment: @Offler Nir said it: You can't inspect the bodies of methods (e.g. searching for local variables) using reflection. You'll need to decompile some way, or use Roslyn as Tigran suggests.